# isTranslucent and titleTextAttributes are not working ios swift

Tags: ios, swift

```
    lazy var navigationBar = UINavigationBar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 20, width: screen_width, height: 44))

    navigationBar.barTintColor = highorange
    navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
    navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: grayblack]
```

I initialized a navigationbar, and the bartintcolor is working. But isTranslucent and titleTextAttributes are not changed.

Answer (score 0):

In my sample it works.

about isTranslucent property from apple documentation

> If you set this property to false on a navigation bar with a translucent custom background image, the navigation bar provides an opaque background for the image using black if the navigation bar has black style, white if the navigation bar has default, or the navigation bar’s barTintColor if a custom value is defined.

titleTextAttributes also works when i added the code below

```
navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.green]
let item = UINavigationItem(title: "Hello world")
navigationBar.setItems([item], animated: false)
```

I got following result:

[image]